# Perl: Weird Tie::File behaviour in Windows as opposed to Unix

Tags: windows, linux, perl, bash, powershell

I have this perl script that uses `Tie::File`. 
In Linux(Ubuntu) when I invoke the script via Bash it works as expected but in Windows when I invoke the script via Powershell it behaves weirdly (check P.S. below).

**Code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use CommonStringTasks;

if ( @ARGV != 4 ) {
   print "ERROR:Inadequate/Redundant arguments.\n";
   print "Usage: perl <pl_executable> <path/to/peer_main.java> <peer_main.java>\n";
   print "       <score_file_index> <port_step_index>\n";
   print $ARGV[0], "\n";
   print $ARGV[1], "\n";
   print $ARGV[2], "\n";
   print $ARGV[3], "\n";
   exit 1;
}

my $PEER_DIR = $ARGV[0];
my $PEER_FILE = $ARGV[1];
my $PEER_PACKAGE = "src/planetlab/app";
my $PEER_PATH = "${PEER_DIR}/${PEER_PACKAGE}/${PEER_FILE}";

# Check if args are tainted ...

# Check $PEER_PATH file permissions ...

open(my $file, "+<", "$PEER_PATH")
   or
die("File ", $PEER_FILE, " could not be opened for editing:$!");

# Edit the file and change variables for debugging/deployment setup.
# Number demanglers:
# -flock -> arg2 -> 2 stands for FILE_EX
# Options (critical!):
# -Memory: Inhibit caching as this will allow record changes on the fly.
tie my @fileLines, 
    'Tie::File', 
    $file,
    memory => 0
      or 
    die("File ", $PEER_FILE, " could not be tied with Tie::File:$!");

flock $file, 2;

my $i = 0;
my $scoreLine = "int FILE_INDEX = " . $SCORE . ";";
my $portLine = "int SERVER_PORT = " . $PORT . ";";
my $originalScoreLine = "int FILE_INDEX =";
my $originalPortLine = "int SERVER_PORT =";

(tied @fileLines)->defer;

while (my $line = <$file>) {
   if ( ($line =~ m/($scoreLine)/) && ($SCORE+1 > 0) ) {
      print "Original line (score): ", "\n", $scoreLine, "\n";
      chomp $line;
      $line = substr($line, 0, -($scoreDigits+1));
      $line = $line . (++$SCORE) . ";";
      print "Editing line (score): ", $i, "\n",  trimLeadSpaces($fileLines[$i]), "\n";
      $fileLines[$i] = $line;
      print "Line replaced with:\n", trimLeadSpaces($line), "\n";
      next;
   }
   if ( ($line =~ m/($portLine)/) && ($PORT > 0) ) {
      print "Original line (port): ", "\n", $portLine, "\n";
      chomp $line;
      $line = substr($line, 0, -($portDigits+1));
      $line = $line . (++$PORT) . ";";
      print "Editing line (port): ", $i, "\n",  trimLeadSpaces($fileLines[$i]), "\n";
      $fileLines[$i] = $line;
      print "Line replaced with:\n", trimLeadSpaces($line), "\n";
      last;
   }

   # Restore original settings.
   if ( ($line =~ m/($originalScoreLine)/) && ($SCORE < 0) ) {
      print "Restoring line (score) - FROM: ", "\n", $fileLines[$i], "\n";
      $fileLines[$i] = "    private static final int FILE_INDEX = 0;";
      print "Restoring line (score) - TO: ", "\n", $fileLines[$i], "\n";
      next;
   }
   if ( ($line =~ m/($originalPortLine)/) && ($PORT < 0) ) {
      print "Restoring line (port) - FROM: ", "\n", $fileLines[$i], "\n";
      $PORT = abs($PORT);
      $fileLines[$i] = "    private static final int SERVER_PORT = " . $PORT . ";";
      print "Restoring line (port) - TO: ", "\n", $fileLines[$i], "\n";
      last;
   }
} continue {
   $i++;
}

(tied @fileLines)->flush;

untie @fileLines;
close $file;
```

The perl version in both OSes is 5+(in Windows Active-State Perl with CPAN modules).
Could it be the way I open the filehandle? Any ideas anyone?

P.S.: The first version had a `while (<$file>)` and instead of `$line` I used the `$_` variable but when I did that I had a behaviour where specific lines would not be edited but instead the file would get appended with a hundred newlines or so followed by the (correctly) edited line and so on. I also had a warning about `$fileLines[$i]` being uninitialized!Clearly something's wrong with the `Tie::File` structure in Windows or something else that I am not aware of. Same erratic behaviour takes place with the changes and in Linux(Ubuntu) behaviour again is as expected.

Comment: "**Clearly something's wrong with the Tie::File structure in Windows**" Well, maybe so, but that is not so clear to me. What is the purpose of this script? Why are you even using `Tie::File`?

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a minimal example? A agree with Sinan, I can't fully understand why you are even using `Tie::File`. Also I haven't seen `flock` used with `Tie::File` before; this doesn't mean it can't work.

Comment: @SinanÜnür The script edits a file because I am compiling multiple Java files with a different value. It would be tedious to do this by hand. As far as `Tie::File` is concerned, what are you suggesting? I mean it does its job well although some state it's an overkill for what it was supposed to do.

Comment: @JoelBerger Ignore the if conditionals. Imagine an if conditional in the while loop. If I find a line that matches i.e `int x = 0`; I change it to `int x = 1;` I call it again and it finds `int x = 1;` then it edits the line to `int x = 2`; and so on. The arguments are properly changed in its call. The last call restores the line (`int x = 0;` in the referred example).

Comment: I will also try to use the `-MCPAN` option when calling `perl` to see if that works.

Comment: The `CPAN` module (which is what is loaded when `-MCPAN` is passed) is for installing other modules, it will not help a running script

Comment: version 5+ just means not archaic, if you think versions might be a problem, can you please post whole version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OPs question is vague, and lacks input and expected output. Therefore I will simply note some of my concerns:

First, using `Tie::File` and `<$file>` and `flock` on the same handle seems to be both overkill and dangerous. I would recommend simply using `Tie::File` to iterate and to edit, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'filename';

foreach my $linenum ( 0..$#lines ) {
  if ($lines[$linenum] =~ /something/) {
    $lines[$linenum] = 'somethingelse';
  }
}
```

Perhaps better than edit inline, as `Tie::File` allows, copy the file to a backup, iterate over the lines using `<$file>`, then write to a new file with the old name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy 'move';

my $infile = $ARGV[0];

move( $infile, "$infile.bak");

open my $inhandle, '<', "$infile.bak";
open my $outhandle, '>', $infile;

while( my $line = <$inhandle> ) {
  if ($line =~ /something/) {
    $line = 'somethingelse';
  }
  print $outhandle $line; 
}
```

Second, the `-MModule` flag simply translates to a `use Module;` at the top of the script. Therefore `-MCPAN` is `use CPAN;`, however loading the `CPAN` module does nothing for the script. `CPAN.pm` gives a script the ability to install modules.

Third, we will be able to help better if you give and example input, an expected output, and a stripped down script that clearly shows how this operation is to perform while still failing in the same way that the actual script does.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of my problems. 
The reason was the **record separator!** 
`Tie::File` expected in Windows a `/r/n` record separator so it read the whole file in just one pass. My files are in *UTF-8*, with *Unix line endings*.
That is why when I was traversing the `$fileLines` and accessed any index beyond 0 I got from perl a warning that the string was not initialized. Fixed the problem and now I am ready to go on! :D

P.S.: Mr Joel Berger I am marking your answer as valid/appropriate because you really tried helping me and I followed your first advice about the file handle :). 
Thank you everyone for assisting me xD xD xD

Comment: glad to help. Actually I should have thought of the line endings first; that is a gotcha that comes up quite often when switching between platforms.

Comment: That's all well & good, but the point is you put so much extraneous stuff in your question that to make it especially **hard** for other people to help you. It seems like you are going through extremely weird contortions to achieve what is seemingly a very straightforward task. To each his own, I guess.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Usually people complain about being vague by asking general questions and giving too little information. I have to disagree with you since I posted code with enough parts omitted (even the `if then else` parts could be ignored because I said so) to make the post easy and readable and gave an example too of what it does. I am pretty sorry if I don't meet up to your expectations. P.S.: I am not an experienced programmer in Perl so I can't say whether my contortions are really weird ;) P.S.2: I never implied that you didn't help or didn't want to help (just in case you took offense :D)